# I cannot get the body data from http.post response with Ionic 3, but I am getting data when using Postman

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am getting a blank response on http post method in Ionic 3. I an not able to post data.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    data: any = {};

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        var url = 'http://testing.com/api/coreapi.php';
        let body = {
            project_code: '1',
            request_code: 'get_machine_data'

        }

        console.log(body);

        this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json)
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(body)
                console.log(data); //Getting blank response in network tab
            });
    }
}
```

when, I run ionic-serve, and got the information from console:

```
Response {_body: " ↵", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
```

and when I check network tab it shows blank response.

My Postman api response is something like this

```
"project_url" : "http://example.com"
"response_code": "STATUS_OK"
```

I am new to Ionic.

Comment: What body data are you expecting in the response?  A lot of POST calls result in empty response bodies.  Is this possibly OK?

Comment: i am expecting this in body "project_url" : " http://example.com" ......The same what i am getting in postman,.

Comment: What happens if you change `res => res.json` to `res => res.json()`?

Comment: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input..I am getting this error in console.

Comment: To me, this suggests that the server is not sending a response.  Therefore, the most likely problem is something missing from the request.  Do you have docs for the server API?

Comment: Yes i have docs for this api.

Comment: Can you please share a link?

Comment: Yes i can share the code with you.give me your email id please.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't offer free private support.  I'll summarise what we've discussed in an answer below.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok no problem @ Alex Peters

Answer (score 1):

The server is responding with an empty body.

This is more likely to be **a problem with the request** rather than a problem with your code.

You will need to look more closely at the API docs for the server you're calling, and change your request accordingly.  Without public access to the API docs for this server and which specific endpoint you're calling, it's unlikely that anyone on this site will be able to offer you any fix for the request.

You may wish to isolate your problem from Ionic entirely by testing your server API calls in a separate tool, such as [Advanced REST Client](https://install.advancedrestclient.com/) (which I haven't personally used or tested).

One other small issue (although this isn't affecting the server response) is that you call `res.json` in the `map` line.  This should be `res.json()`.  (This change will cause an additional error to display in the console, because you're not receiving JSON from the server in the first place.)